# Save data to chrome storage in web worker?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, web-worker

I have designed my extension to have a great user experience as all calculation-intensive operations are side-loaded off the main thread and run in a worker. I now have batches of jpeg images (converted to base64 for storage), and I find that chrome.storage.local is not available in my worker to write the data. I have no intention of COPYING all the data I have over to some content script so I can store it there.

How can I save to `chrome.storage.local` on a worker? Is there a way I can route or expose the API?

Comment: There's no way to plumb the API so you'll have to use the standard worker messaging which is essentially copying but it should be fast since it uses the structured cloning algorithm.

Comment: @wOxxOm but is set() asynchronous in the sense that the values passed are by reference? Will it take ~couple ms to call storage.set( { key : result } ) if results is several MB? Or will it copy everything on the main thread? I don't want any functions at all on the content thread that take more than a frame. (I don't care how long it takes to evaluate, but the CALL must be fast)

Comment: The speed of set() shouldn't be a factor unless your object is unusually deeply nested, like 10000 levels deep.

Comment: @wOxxOm well that's good to know... Will the eventlistener on postmessage only be called after the data is already copied?

Comment: That's how all messaging works, yes.

Comment: @wOxxOm Something must be wrong. I have implemented this exactly, and all my page animations freeze for three seconds while calling chrome.storage.local.set()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218237/discussion-between-hackstaar-and-woxxom).

Comment: Sounds bad. Try creating a Blob, send its URL to the background script and let it save it to storage, see examples of using URL.createObjectURL.